# Why is apache still logging my PHP Notices?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, logging

I have edited `/etc/php5/acpache2/php.ini` and set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` then restarted apache, yet my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is still filling up with `PHP Notice:  Undefined index:` errors

And yes, it may be best practise to address these, and I will in time, but for now my website works fine but my logs are becoming insanely large to the point where the fill the partition and the whole thing grinds to a halt.

Comment: Check if your php code call `error_reporting()` function, this could overrides your php.ini settings.